# Why doesn’t this thread terminate?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to use the python threading module. As I am sysadmin, I struggle a little bit when developing; and this concept is kind of new for me. I launch two threads and I want to stop them, when the main thread sets a flag to `False`:

```
class My_Thread( threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, thread_name, count):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id      = thread_id
        self.thread_name    = thread_name
        self.count          = count

    def run(self):
        do_job(self.thread_name, self.thread_id, self.count)

def do_job(t_name, t_id, count):
    while not get_kill():
        print "It is "+str(time.time())+" and I am "+str(t_name)
        print get_kill()
        time.sleep(count)

kill = False

def get_kill():
    return kill

def set_kill(state):
    kill = state

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = My_Thread(1, "Thread-1", 2)
    b = My_Thread(2, "Thread-2", 1)
    a.start()
    b.start()

    while(True):
        try:
            pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt,ki:
            set_kill(True)
            sys.exit(0)
```

But the value is never read as changed in both threads and they don't exit. Why is this value not properly read from threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem**

In `set_kill()`, you are creating a new local variable `kill` setting it to `state`, and returning from the function.  You are not actually updating the value of `kill` in the global scope.

To do that, you would need to have:

```
def set_kill(state):
    global kill
    kill = state
```

**A better way**

Using globals like that is generally considered bad practice, you probably want to convert your `kill` variable and functions into an object, to encapsulate that data and behaviour together:

```
class Kill(object):
    kill = False
    def get(self):
        return self.kill
    def set(self, value):
        self.kill = value
```

Which you would use like this:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, thread_name, count, kill):
        self.kill = kill
        ...

    def do_job(self, ...):
        while not self.kill.get():
            ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kill = Kill()
    a = My_Thread(1, "Thread-1", 2, kill)
    b = My_Thread(2, "Thread-2", 1, kill)
    ...
    kill.set(True)
```

Comment: Using an object doesn't really improve much, since the object is still global, and the threads are still looking at a global flag to determine whether to stop. It's just a fancier flag. Passing the `kill` object to the threads as a parameter might be more useful.

Comment: I've update the answer along those line, that is much better again!

Comment: You create a static and not instance variable here, which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: @Voo It would make a difference if `kill` was a `list` and I was doing something like `self.kill.append()`, because then I would be updating the static list, but for simple assignment, as I am accessing it via `self`, it updates the *instance's* reference `kill`.  In other words, on construction, the instance get's it's own reference to the global `False` singlton. On `set`, it updates *its* reference to whatever is passed.  That does not affect the static `Kill.kill` reference at all, which will always be `False`.

Comment: @Voo See the static `kill = False` as a kind of default value. The `self.kill = value` sets the instance variable to a (maybe different) value, and that's what counts, along with the fact that `return self.kill` returns the first of (instance, static) one that exists.

Comment: @Jamie oh I know that (and why) it works, but I haven't seen that in idiomatic python code - it's usually people coming from java, etc who do it. It's shorter, but only reasonably safe for immutable values. Not a fan of it, but since you know what you're doing it's no problem.. just a bit worried about confusing newcomers.

Comment: Many thanks! Your answers helped me understanding the working of it